# Stack html divs with different width and height?

Tags: html, css

What is the best way to stack multiple divs without generating space in between?

I'm using css float with different height and width to achieve the current outcome:

```
*{margin:0;padding:0;}

#main{
  background: blue;
  max-width:1000px;
  margin:0 auto;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-align:center;
}

div>div{
  background: green;
  width:33.33333%;
  float:left;
  border:1px solid grey;
  padding:5px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  height:100%;

}

div>div>div{
  width:100%;
  background:yellow;
  height:100%;
}
```

http://codepen.io/vincentccw/pen/WvExKB

As you can see the outcome isn't really what I intended to achieve, blue spacing in between and horizontal line breaks......

[image]

What I want to do is have all the divs arrange them-self automatically and take up whatever blue space there is left to occupy....

Comment: It is called Masonry layout. Have a look on JavaScript libraries / jQuery plugins exist to achieve the layout: http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-masonry-layout/

Comment: Indeed - http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: @HashemQolami Thanks I think will go will this JavaScript solution, very useful indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take a look at flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Also as Hashem pointed out, but then a css solution: http://demosthenes.info/blog/844/Easy-Masonry-Layout-With-Flexbox

Comment: Thanks for the flexbox and Mansonry solution, since flexbox is still very new and browser supports aren't great, I'm gonna go with the Masonry way.